# Overlay on hover in React, the JS way

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to do an overlay when hovering images in React with this tutorial: [w3 schools tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_overlay.asp).

My code:

```
<div className="grid-item" key={movie.id}>
                            <img className="grid-images" alt={movie.title} src={movie.src}>
                                <div className="overlay">{movie.title}</div>
                    </div>
```

My error message: `Parsing error: Expected corresponding JSX closing tag for <img>`

As JSX doesn't allow not closing the img-tag, this method doesn't work. I can't seem to find an alternative how to do this in React with css. Anyone? :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to self-close the img tag by adding '/' just before the >:

```
<img className="grid-images" alt={movie.title} src={movie.src} />
```

Comment: You are correct! When I tried this I had a totally different bug in the CSS that was the reason it wasn't working so I got confused. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome :) Please remember to mark your issue as solved :)